# Importing pytorch geometric results in an error message

Tags: pytorch, conda, pytorch-geometric

I'm suddenly unable to import pytorch geometric and I cannot figure out why. I've added a screenshot of the packages in my conda environment and the error message that I get when I try to `import torch_geometric`.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
```

Error message:

> OSError: dlopen(/Users/anstercharles/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN2at8internal13_parallel_runExxxRKNSt3__18functionIFvxxmEEE
> Referenced from: /Users/anstercharles/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so
> Expected in: /Users/anstercharles/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
> in /Users/anstercharles/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so

Running:

```
conda list pytorch
```

Gives me:

| Name | Version | Build | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pytorch | 1.9.0 | cpu_py38h490fcb8_1 | conda-forge |
| pytorch-cluster | 1.5.9 | py38_torch_1.9.0_cpu | rusty1s |
| pytorch-geometric | 1.7.2 | py38_torch_1.9.0_cpu | rusty1s |
| pytorch-scatter | 2.0.8 | py38_torch_1.9.0_cpu | rusty1s |
| pytorch-sparse | 0.6.11 | py38_torch_1.9.0_cpu | rusty1s |
| pytorch-spline-conv | 1.2.1 | py38_torch_1.9.0_cpu | rusty1s |

[image: I have the packages installed and I was using them just a few minutes ago.]

---

### Additional Details

- OS: MacOS Mojave
- Anaconda 3
- Python 3.8

Comment: Please, avoid posting code/text as image.

Comment: Ok. I rectified it.

Comment: This is very likely due to [channel mixing](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels) (e.g., **pytorch**, **anaconda**, **conda-forge**). However, seeing only the Anaconda Navigator view doesn't include the required information. Could you please add the output from running `conda list pytorch` (at command line)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will edit it in the question above.

Comment: I used conda install pytorch-geometric -c rusty1s -c conda-forge to download pytorch-geometric. Shouldn't that have prevented channel mixing?

Comment: There's also a large portion of the error message that I cannot include in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate the error. [The documentation in the README](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric#anaconda), to use

```bash
conda install pytorch-geometric -c rusty1s -c conda-forge
```

does not match [the order that is actually used in the build](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/conda/pytorch-geometric/build_conda.sh#L33), which has the channel order:

```bash
-c defaults -c pytorch -c conda-forge -c rusty1s
```

### Workaround

I find it works using:

```bash
conda create -n foo -c defaults -c pytorch -c conda-forge -c rusty1s pytorch-geometric
```

Answer (score 0):

following @merv answer, I resolved it by changing my python version from 3.8 to 3.9 
I created another environment as follows: (M1 Mac Big Sur)

- python : 3.9.7
- pytorch : 1.9.1
- pytorch-geometric : 2.0.1